# Transferring datastore backup between apps; how to add an app to another app with edit permissions?

Tags: google-app-engine

The documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/datastoreadmin#restoring_data_to_another_app) states:

> 1. Using the Google Cloud Platform Console, locate the project that has
>      the bucket used for your backups and add the target app (the app you
>      are restoring to) to the project team with Edit permissions.

Where and how do I add the target app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the receivers [App Engine Service Account](https://console.cloud.google.com/permissions/serviceaccounts) ie: `YOURAPPID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` which you will then add to the [Permissions section](https://console.cloud.google.com/permissions/projectpermissions) of the Application generating the backup.